# I want to widen the left viewer in rails.vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I use rails.vim which is great. One thing that annoys me is that every time I open a file, the left window (directory viewer) is set to its default width(24 cols). It's too narrow to see the file path. Even if I widen it, it comes back to its default size when I open a file.

How can I change the default size? Or for better, how can I prevent it from auto-resizing?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the rails.vim plugin has a directory viewer -- my best guess would be that you're actually seeing NERDTree's directory viewer.

Try adding this to your `~/.vimrc` file to set a custom width:

```
let g:NERDTreeWinSize=40
```

Comment: Did you completely close and reopen vim after doing this?